# Spring JDBC With transaction commit fails

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I'm working on a Spring JDBC project using transactions.
I'm using PostgreSQL as a database :

Here is my spring configuration :

```
<tx:annotation-driven/> 
<bean id="transactionManager"class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">    
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMainDatabase"/>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSourceMainDatabase" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db_toto"/>
    <property name="username" value="toto"/>
    <property name="password" value="toto"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="16000"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

In my java code, I have the following :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly=false)
public void synchronize( Exobox exobox ) {
    daoExotool.updateDerniereSynchro(exobox,new Date(),new Date(),true,10);     
}
```

The DAO code is the following :

```
public void updateDerniereSynchro(Exobox exobox, Date dateFinSynchro,
        Date dateSynchroDerniereDonnee, boolean synchroOk, int nbPositions) {
    getJdbcTemplate().update(sqlInsertSynchro,exobox.getExoboxId(),dateFinSynchro,
            dateSynchroDerniereDonnee,nbPositions,synchroOk);       
}
```

The Query used is this one :

```
private final String sqlInsertSynchro =     
        "INSERT INTO t_exotool_synchro_log("+
                "synchro_log_exobox_id, synchro_log_date_fin,synchro_log_date_data,"
                + "synchro_log_nb_positions,synchro_log_ok)"+
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? , ?)";
```

The synchronize method is itself called from another class, as follows :

```
public class DbInserts {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
       exoboxYgos = context.getBean("exoboxYgos",Exobox.class);
       synchro = context.getBean(IServiceSynchro.class);
       context.close(); 
       synchro.synchronize(exoboxYgos);
   }
}
```

When I launch my application, the log shows me this :

```
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Creating new transaction with name [fr.axione.exotool.service.ImplServiceSynchro.synchronize]:   PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Acquired Connection [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db_exotool, UserName=toto, PostgreSQL Native Driver] for JDBC transaction
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Executing prepared SQL update
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO t_exotool_synchro_log(synchro_log_exobox_id, synchro_log_date_fin,synchro_log_date_data,synchro_log_nb_positions,synchro_log_ok)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? , ?)]
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] SQL update affected 1 rows
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db_exotool, UserName=toto, PostgreSQL Native Driver]
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db_exotool, UserName=toto, PostgreSQL Native Driver] after transaction
DEBUG [ 13 août 2014 10:52:56 ] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

My problem is that the inserted line is never stored in the Database itself.

On the other hand, if I set :

```
<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
```

The insertion works but the rollback has no effect.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you very much,
Emmanuel.

Comment: what is your aoExotool.updateDerniereSynchro is doing? can you post code please?

Comment: Hello, and thank you. I posted my DAO code in my question. I tried to implement the transaction mechanism without annotations, using the PlatformTransactionManager manually, and everything worked fine this way. Maybe I have a problem with my <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/ configuration....

Comment: Please post the code that directly invoke: `public void synchronize( Exobox exobox )` - is it in the same class like the `synchronize` method?

Comment: Hi, Ralph : I posted the code which is invoking the synchronize method in my original question. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you closing the context? You shouldn't do that, at least not at the point that you are doing it now.

Comment: M. Deinum, if I indeed close my context after the call to the Transactionl method, things work as expected. Do you happen to know why is it so ? Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Closing the context leads to cleaning up resources (like closing the datasource, destroying the transaction manager etc.). You are basically loosing some of the beans you need to properly run your application. What you are trying to do is basically forcefully close MS-Word and afterwards try to save a document and then find your changes aren't there.

Comment: OK thanks. How can I mark this question as solved by you ? (I'm quite new to this forum...)